# Can't access json data

Tags: javascript, html, json

I know this is a simple question, but I can't access the data in my json object.  It looks like this:

```
var string={"data":
[
        {
        "city": "Gansu",
        "value": "#000"
        },
        {
        "city": "Ningzhau",
        "value": "#000"
        },
        {
        "city": "Chongqing",
        "value": "#000"
        }
     ]
 };
 var obj =JSON.parse(string);
```

To test it, I am doing: `document.write(obj.data[0].city);` which I think should return Gansu.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with the last line of code and how to fix it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you shouldn't have parsed the JSON:

```
var string={"data":
[
        {
        "city": "Gansu",
        "value": "#000"
        },
        {
        "city": "Ningzhau",
        "value": "#000"
        },
        {
        "city": "Chongqing",
        "value": "#000"
        }
     ]
 };

alert(string.data[0].city);
```

Answer (score 1):

'string' is already an object, no need to convert it.

Just do `string.data[0].city;`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add quotes around the JSON data, hence it's actually an object. [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) expects a string. It should look something like this:

```
var string = '{"data":[{"city": "Gansu","value": "#000"},{"city": "Ningzhau","value": "#000"},{"city": "Chongqing","value": "#000"}]}';
// ----------^-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^

var obj = JSON.parse(string);
document.write(obj.data[0].city);
```